# insert record after particular row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I want to insert records into the sql server 2008 table,using c# asp.net,the column values are all declared as "nvarchar",and the 1st column subid is the primary key.In my code,i retrieve the last coulmn id,increment it and use it as the subid for new record,when i insert a record,it does not get stored sequentially,instead it gets stored in the middle somewhere.So the next time i try to retrieve the last id column value(though i use "order by"),it gives the existing value,which when incremented,gives an error,"duplicate values,not allowed".
this is my code to retrieve the last id value and increment it:

```
       SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 subid FROM subjects                         

       ORDER BY subid DESC", con1);         

             reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows == false)
            {
                Label4.Text = "1";
                reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                while (reader.Read()) // if can read row from database
                {

                    id = reader[0].ToString();

                }
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                int j = n + 1;
                Label4.Text = j.ToString();
```

my insert code is:

```
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM subjects ORDER BY       
        subid DESC", con);
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("subjects");
        da.Fill(ds, "subjects");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["subjects"].NewRow(); 
        row["subid"] = Label4.Text;
        row["dept"] = (string)Session["deptmnt"];
        row["yr"] = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        row["sem"] = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
        row["subname"] = TextBox1.Text;
        row["subcode"] = TextBox2.Text;

        ds.Tables["subjects"].Rows.Add(row);
        da.Update(ds, "subjects");

        Label10.Visible = true;
        con.Close();
```

how do i make the value get inserted as the last row,pls help.
my subid has values like "IT10001","EC10001" to identify the department based on the 1st two letters thats why im using varchar!

Comment: This approach is a really horrible design - you should never use the "SELECT MAX(..)+1" approach to create new ID values. This is **NOT SAFE** under load - if more than a single user is using this application, rather sooner than later you'll have duplicates. **Don't do this!** Use an `INT IDENTITY` column in your table and let SQL Server handle the uniqueness of the ID for you.

Comment: @marc_s Out of interest, how many times a day do you have to tell people that? ;-)

Comment: @Bridge: **way too many times!** :-(

Comment: @marc_s Haha, I try and help when I can, but you usually get there first :)

Answer (score 2):

ordering on NVarchChar fields will be done as string. Therefore, It will keep happening with **NVARCHAR**. The correct way is to `add an integer column` in your database and set it to `auto-increment`. This will ensure that you don't have to get max value each time before adding a new row.

Comment: ,thank you,but,i have created many tables,with varchar,so,now i cant alter the table also as integer,so,pls give another alternate way

Comment: not possible with nvarchar. you will have to swallow the pill

Comment: If you identify a bad design, change it as soon as possible. You're only opening yourself for more pain later.

Comment: @sweko my subid has values like "IT10001","EC10001" to identify the department based on the 1st two letters thats why im using varchar

Comment: Than the code that does `int n = Convert.ToInt32(id);` will fail, as `EC10001` is not a valid number.

Answer (score 2):

You have the expression `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM subjects ORDER BY subid DESC`.

If `subid` is NVarChar, as you have said, the ordering is done on strings, not numbers. And that means '10' <  '2'. Assuming you have 1000 records, they will be ordered:

```
1 
10
11
..
19
100
101
...
1000
2
20
21
...
...
999
```

so, each and every time you try to get the largest number, you'll get the string '999' back, since it's lexically largest.

The simplest solution is to change the column to an integer, since it's actually an integer.
If you absolutely, positively cannot change it, then at least pad the value with zeroes, so have "0001", "0002", "0010" instead of "1", "2", "10".

Additionally, using the MAX+1 approach, requires that you do everything using a transaction, because of concurrency problems. Using an int identity as a primary key solves those problems for you.